# ADX, KQL and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, kql, adx

I have a table in pandas dataframe, and need to go through a column and check if I have that value in ADX. how can I do that? I was thinking of setting each entry in pandas as a variable, and call it in KQL. Any ideas how?
sth like this, but not sure how:

```
val=df['col_name'][0]

%%kql 
table_name
| where value == $val
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note sure I understand the requirement, best if you can specify a minimal example with the df in Python, and a table in ADX (using datatable operator).

Anyway, just fyi, you can copy variables from Jupyter to Kusto using let, see [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4mC5.png)